# group by name and order by date and each group order by date in linq

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following table.
Name Date
A    10/04/2016
A    10/03/2016
A    10/05/2016
B    10/02/2016
B    10/01/2016
B    10/03/2016
C    10/05/2016
C    10/02/2016
C    10/04/2016

I would like to display this
Name    Date
B    10/01/2016
B    10/02/2016
B    10/03/2016
C    10/02/2016
C    10/04/2016
C    10/05/2016
A    10/03/2016
A    10/04/2016
A    10/05/2016

How to create a query  to get this result.

Comment: any effort from your side?

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = new[]
{
    new { Name = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/04/2016") },
    new { Name = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/03/2016") },
    new { Name = "A", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/05/2016") },

    new { Name = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/02/2016") },
    new { Name = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/01/2016") },
    new { Name = "B", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/03/2016") },

    new { Name = "C", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/05/2016") },
    new { Name = "C", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/02/2016") },
    new { Name = "C", Date = DateTime.Parse("10/04/2016") },
};

// LINQ to Objects
elements
    .GroupBy(e => e.Name)                         // grouping by name                
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(e => e.Date))  // order elements by date      
    .OrderBy(group => group.First().Date)         // order groups by date
    .SelectMany(group => group);                  // compose groups 

// LINQ to Entities
elements
    .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(e => e.Date))
    .OrderBy(group => group.FirstOrDefault().Date)                   
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(group => group);
```

Comment: My query is   var group = db.Itineraries
                            .GroupBy(d => d.JobListID)
                            .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d.DutyDate))
                            .OrderBy(e => e.First().DutyDate)
                            .SelectMany(e => e)
                            .ToList();

Comment: But I have the error "The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead." I replace the First() to FirstOrDefault().It does not display correctly

Comment: @NayLinHtike added a possible solution for LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need groupby but only orderby can fullfil your task:

```
yourList.OrderBy(l => l.Date).ThenBy(l => l.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you provide more information. Such as, the object type containing the data. Is it a custom model or a DataTable? Any how, I will try both.

```
var result = dataTable.Rows.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

OR

```
var result = Foo.GroupBy(x => x.Name).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: my query is like "db.table.asEnumerable().GroupBy(x=>x.Name).OrderBy(x=x.Date);

Comment: Then you should be fine. Although I noticed in the OrderBy you have a typo. You're missing > before x.Date. It should read x => x.Date

Answer (score 0):

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0SfhAz

This is the fiddle with the code. For some reason, I can't get the fiddle to write out the values in the list.

I originally did this in LinqPad, and here is the output I got from the code in the fiddle when in LinqPad

1. B 10/1/2016
2. B 10/2/2016
3. B 10/3/2016
4. C 10/2/2016
5. C 10/4/2016
6. C 10/5/2016
7. A 10/3/2016
8. A 10/4/2016
9. A 10/5/2016

I don't know why I can't just do a writeline on the .net fiddle, but it is being difficult. In case the fiddle doesn't work for you, here it the linq query I used for this

var orderedList = originalList.OrderBy(x => x.SomeDate).GroupBy(y => y.Name);

There may be better approaches, but this looked to solve your issue